# Deleting an element from vector of type structure

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I am trying this piece of code. What I am trying to do is to delete an element from vector of type structure

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _detail
{
    int y;
}detail;

typedef struct _list
{
    int x;
    detail det;
}list;

std::vector<list> v;
list li[5];

void PushElements()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        li[i].x = i+2;
        li[i].det.y = i+3;
        v.push_back(li[i]);
    }
}

void display()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].x << " ";
        cout << v[i].det.y << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void DeleteElement()
{


std::vector<list>::iterator it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&list::detail::y, _1) == 3);
v.erase(it);

}

int main()
{
    PushElements();
    display();
    DeleteElement();
    cout << "After Deleting...................." << endl;
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

While compiling I get following errors:

```
error C3083: 'detail': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
error C2039: 'y' : is not a member of '_list'
error C2065: 'y' : undeclared identifier
```

I don't understand what this error is and how to solve it. Can somebody help me to solve this error??

Answer (score 2):

```
&list::detail::y
```

`detail` is the name of a type that isn't nested in `list`. `list` has a member of *type* `detail` named `y`.

I think you want to form a pointer to member of member, but as far as I can tell, it's not possible. You're better off using a lambda to do the comparisons. Something like:

```
std::find_if(..., ..., [something](const list& l) { return l.det.y == something; } );
```

On another note, identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace. `_list` and `_detail` aren't strictly allowed.